# Can't get childnodes.length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, html-table

I'm trying to find a node that contains an image, and then find a specific string in that image's tag.  But I don't know when on the page the image tag will occur, except that it appears only in `td` elements that are classed as `bodyTextSmall`.  That should get me there, right?

Everything works just fine, until I try to get the `length` of the `childNodes` property.  See the line above.

Is this the right code, or is there another way to find out if a specific `td` has an `img` tag somewhere inside it?  I'm tearing out what little hair I have left, because from what little I know of JavaScript, this is how it's supposed to work.

The problem is that I only know by the `img` tag whether I need to format the `td` tag, and I don't assemble the `td` tags and can't get into that part of the site to make changes directly.  I've already tried CSS selectors to see if I can style parts of images, but there are inline styles that I can't override.  Again, that's part of the site that I can't control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTables(dRef) {

var d = document;
var dMid = d.getElementById('mainContent');
var dTabs = dMid.getElementsByTagName('td');

  //  Attempts to load table cells...
  for (var i = 0; i < dTabs.length; i++) {
    //  Attempts to detect the specific cell type...
    if (dTabs[i].className == "bodyTextSmall") {
      //  Attempts to locate the parts inside this cell...
      var myNodes = i.ChildNodes;  //  This part runs, but I can't get "ChildNodes.length" to work

      //  Attempts to notify the user...
      alert(dTabs[i].className + ':  ' + i);
    }
  }

}

window.onload = getTables;

</script>
```

So, now I've switched to jQuery, and I'm getting the same problem.  I can tell what image is where, but I can't do anything to the image itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function getTables() {
    //  Locates the correct container for images...
    $('#mainContent img').each(function(idx, item) {
        var tImgs = item.src;
        if (tImgs.indexOf("-ds.") > 0) {
            window.alert(tImgs);
            $(this).append('Here is a message about the image.');  //nothing happens here
        }

    });

}

window.onload = getTables;

</script>
```

Again, this jQuery code responds by responding to any image that has "-ds." anywhere in the src.  I can't get anything else to happen.  I do know that $(img).append will affect EVERY image, so the script is capable of doing something.

This has now become a case of getting more than what I want or nothing at all, and it's really starting to get on my last nerves.

Answer (score 5):

`i.ChildNodes` is undefined.
You mean `childNodes`.

Also, `i` is a number, not a DOM element.
You mean `dTabs[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

`var myNodes = dTabs[i].ChildNodes;`

Answer (score 1):

```
function dFixIt() {

    $('#mainContent img').each(function(idx, item) {
        var tImgs = item.src;
        if (tImgs.indexOf("-ds.") > 0) {
            $(this).parent().after('Here is a message about the image');
        }

    });

}
```

This this will locate anything inside an element with the ID "mainContent" if it is an image.  Then it will determine if the string "-ds." is anywhere in the image name.  So "my-friends-ds.jpg" would get something added to it.

If the image is inside a link, the ".parent()" jumps the script outside that link BEFORE adding the message.  That prevents the added content from becoming a link.

If the image is NOT inside a link, remove ".parent()" from the string, and it should add the message directly after the image.